# Waiting a period of time between method executions

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I understand using `setTimeout` and `setInterval` to delay the start of a method, but I've come across a problem. I want to have three cpu players (in a card game) "take turns". They should take their turn, and then have, say, 500ms before the next one goes. Here's the code I want to structure the turn taking (this is, for now, without a human so I want it to run continuously):

```
var whoseTurn = 0;
while (true) {
            setTimeout(takeTurn(players[whoseTurn]), 500);
            whoseTurn = (whoseTurn + 1) % 3;
        }
```

In a separate function:

```
function takeTurn(player) {
        //Now taking a turn
    }
```

The problem is that, after `setTimeout` is called, my code in the first function continues to run, rendering the delay virtually useless.

Comment: Unfortunately it does'nt work that way, the timeout is async, and the loop finishes right away anyway, but in your case it never finishes, it just hangs the browser eventually.

Answer (score 0):

```
var whoseTurn = 0;
while (true) {
        setTimeout(takeTurn(players[whoseTurn]), 500);
        whoseTurn = (whoseTurn + 1) % 3;
}
```

So.. This will create a timer, then increment the turn in a tight loop. And it's not even calling takeTurn because you are calling it (by supplying arguments). Not what you want.

One fix would be to call setInterval, and increment the turn at the end of each go-round. But that doesn't let the turns be variable-length. (I.e. if it takes 100ms, then the next turn will come in 400ms.

The correct way to structure it is to kick off the first turn once, then kick off a timer at the end of each turn:

```
function takeTurn() {
    player = players[whoseTurn];
    //Now taking a turn
    whoseTurn = (whoseTurn + 1) % 3;
    setTimeout(takeTurn, 500);
}

setTimeout(takeTurn, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

First approach would be to use setTimeout or setInterval, whatever you prefer

```
var turnsInt = null
  , whoseTurn = 0
  , players = [....]

function takeTurn() {
   var player = players[whoseTurn]
   ... do stuff

   whoseTurn=(whoseTurn+1)%players.length
}

turnsInt = setInterval(takeTurn, 500)

... some other code in some other place to stop it

if(cond) {
   clearInterval(turnsInt)
}
```

Another approach would be to create chains of promises using jquery promise implementation

```
$.when(takeTurn(1)).then(takeTurn(2)).then(takeTurn(3))


function takeTurn(whoseTurn) {
    var def = $.Deffered()

    ... do stuff

    setTimeout(function() {
       def.resolve()
    }, 500)       

    return def
}
```